# Sum of three variables (Edit Text) without button to print in a fourth variable (Text View)

Tags: java, android, text

I am trying to make an application that calculates the average, I have the fields of name, calif1, cal2, cal3, prom.
But there does not have to be any button that helps to send the operation and return something in prom, so I wanted to see if there was possibility of adding the three variables of calX, without the need for a button and that this result is stored in the variable prom, so after that print in the Text View (which is added constantly, with a refresh or auto sum).
Note: calif1, cal2, cal3 are edit text, and prom is a Text View.
P.D: I was seeing the possibility of using the Action Go ime to act as a button but I do not know if it is possible.

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText8"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:digits="1234567890"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText9"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:digits="1234567890"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText10"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:digits="1234567890"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionGo"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

    </TableRow>
```

Comment: I want to write a method but I dont know if the values entered in edit text have to be in order or randomly??

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of textChangedListener to get a callback when there are values on the editText fields and compute the average.

Ref:[TextWatcher Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Using android:imeoptions can also achieve similar result.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of the textChangeListerner for the three EditText you have. I have included an example with calif1

```
  calif1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() > 0) {
               int a = Integer.parseInt(calif.getText().toString())+                       
               Integer.parseInt(cal1.getText().toString()) + 
               Integer.parseInt(cal2.getText().toString())
               prom.setText(""+a);
                }



            }
        }
    });
```